# progressIndicator use with Manipulate problem

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I made a progressIndicator that works just fine inside Manipulate. I click on a button, which calls a function foo[] which does work, and as it is working, the progressIndicator dynamically shows the progress the function is making.

But when I make a copy of the Manipulate display itself to create a copy of it in another cell, now clicking on the first display stops working, and the progressIndicator in the copy is the one which updates instead.

I have no global symbols. The variables used in the progressIndicator is inside the Manipulate.

Would any one knows how to resolve this? This is a problem, since in making a demo, one must make a copy of the Manipulate itself in the notebook in few places (make few snapshots), and hence no global variables are allowed to be used, else problems can show up.

I made small example to show the problem:

```
Manipulate[
 x,
 Grid[{
   {Control[{{x, 0, "x="}, 0, 1, .1}], SpanFromLeft},

   {Button[Text[Style["run", 11]], {y = 0; foo[]}, ImageSize -> 100, 
     Method -> "Queued"],
    Button[Text[Style["clear", 11]], y = 0, ImageSize -> 100]},

   {Dynamic[ProgressIndicator[y, {0, 1}, ImageSize -> 100]]},
   {Dynamic[Text@Row[{ Style[ y*100 , 11], Style["%", 11]}]]}
   }, Spacings -> {0, .3}],

 {{y, 0}, None},

 TrackedSymbols :> {x}, (*does nothing, just for testing *)

 SynchronousUpdating -> False,
 SynchronousInitialization -> False,
 Initialization :>
  (
   foo[] := Module[{i},
     Do[Pause[.15]; y = i, {i, 0, 1, .1}] (*Pause[] to slow it down*)
     ]
   )
 ]
```

After you run the above, if you copy the Manipulate display itself to a new empty cell, and hit the clear button to reset the counter, and then hit the run the button again on the first Manipulate, you will see that the progress indicator of the second copy is now updating, not the first one.

I must have some shared symbols there, but I do not see where that is.

[image]

Thanks for any help.

**Update 1**

Ok, I added DynamicModule[{symbolsNamesHere}, Manipulate[...]]

This resolved the problem with the 'sharing' between snapshots, so now the ProgresssIndicator works ok in all copies.

But demo CDF is not processed. Here is screen shot

[image]

ps. send email to WRI, as I do not understand this error. Never used DownValues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you could try something like

```
Manipulate[x, 
 Grid[{
    {Control[{{x, 0, "x="}, 0, 1, .1}], SpanFromLeft}, 

    {Button[Text[Style["run", 11]], {y = 0; foo[Unevaluated[y]]}, 
      ImageSize -> 100, Method -> "Queued"],
     Button[Text[Style["clear", 11]], y = 0, 
      ImageSize -> 100]}, 

    {Dynamic[ProgressIndicator[y, {0, 1}, ImageSize -> 100]]}, 

    {Dynamic[Text@Row[{Style[y*100, 11], Style["%", 11]}]]}}, 
  Spacings -> {0, .3}],

 {{y, 0}, None}, 

 TrackedSymbols :> {x, y},(*does nothing,just for testing*)
 SynchronousUpdating -> False, SynchronousInitialization -> False, 
 Initialization :> (foo[a_] := 
    Module[{i}, 
      Do[Pause[.15]; a = i, {i, 0, 1, .1}] (*Pause[] to slow it down*)])
]
```

The only difference is that in this code, `foo` is defined as a function of a parameter instead of using `y` directly which should solve the scoping problems you were having. To update `y` in the `Manipulate` you would then use `foo[Unevaluated[y]]`.

Answer (score 3):

`foo` is the shared symbol.  You can localize it using `DynamicModule[{foo}, Manipulate[...]]`.

**Update**

Apparently, Wolfram Demonstrations will not accept the construct as presented.  As a work-around, perhaps this will work instead:

```
Manipulate[
    (* ... *)
    {{y, 0}, None},
    {foo, None}, (* <-- added an empty manipulator for foo *)
    (* ... *)
    Initialization :>
    (
      foo =.; (* <-- unbind foo before defining it *)
      foo[] := Module[{i},
        Do[Pause[.15]; y = i, {i, 0, 1, .1}] (*Pause[] to slow it down*)
      ]
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I do not understand. Manipulate already is a DynamicModule itself. I have always had many functions in the initialization section of a Manipulate in many demos, and never had problem. In addition, a demo needs to start with a Manipulate[], not DynamicModule[]. Would you know how to resolve this without creating DynamicModule around Manipulate? You are right in that something is shared, but why and how to resolve it. Again, I always had functions in Initialization section before and it never caused a problem, why now? thanks.

Comment: your solution does solve the problem, I am just not sure now I can use it. I need to check with someone at WRI at the demo project to see if this is OK. I always understood that demos must start with Manipulate[]. I am also still very confused as to why I never had this problem show up before even though I used functions in initialization section all the time. thanks!

Comment: Hello WReach, I am afraid it did not work. I added the DynamicModule[] around Manipulate, and localized the symbols needed. Then the problem went away locally, but when I tried to process it to a CDF (i.e. upload the notebook to the demo site), the software rejected it. Please see screen shot. I also send email to someone at WRI asking about this.

Comment: I am not familiar with the Demonstrations restrictions, but I have added a work-around to my response that might do the trick.

Comment: I tried your second solution. And it does work OK locally as before, but again, whenever I upload it, I get the same error with the DownValues symbol showing up. It comes up whenever I add the trick you show with {foo,None}. I think it does not like a function symbol being there. When I remove this, it uploads OK, but the conflict with the progressIndicator comes back. It is that one symbol that is the problem. Strange. I send the notebook to WRI for someone to see why this symbol comes up. The software the processes the notebooks for demo site is very strict.

Comment: ..I think your trick of 'foo=.' is causing DownValues symbol to be generated. DownValues is NOT allowed in demos (security). I looked at the notebook in texteditor and see this symbols there, next to the 'foo'. So, I think doing foo=. is the problem.

Comment: It looks like things like foo=. and Clear[foo] are not allowed in demos, as they can affect user own session by mistake.